# Using memcpy() on a char **buffer

Tags: c, memcpy

If I have a pointer to a message buffer how do I memcpy() into that buffer?  For example say I have the following:

```
char **buffer;
char data[10]

memcpy(*buffer, data, 10);
```

But this doesn't seem to work and always crashes my program, however the compiler doesn't see to mind. Can someone please tell me why? Btw the reason I have a char **buffer is because its being passed as a parameter of the function.

Comment: before writing memory, you need to allocate. also theres nothing to stop you passing a char * into a function..

Comment: `buffer` points nowhere specified and `*buffer` points nowhere specified. Writing to the unknown is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer variable `buffer` does not point to anything. You need to allocate memory and make `buffer` point to it. For instance:

```
buffer = malloc(sizeof(*buffer));
*buffer = malloc(10);
memcpy(*buffer, data, 10);
```